# Calling ImageMagick convert from Java with runtime exec

Tags: java, eclipse, imagemagick, runtime.exec, imagemagick-convert

I want to convert some images from tif to tif to change the photometric interpretation.

I found the ImageMagick Tool and installed it, in command line the following command works and does what i want:

```
 convert my_image.TIF dest.TIF
```

Now i want to start it automatically from a Java program. 
I'm working on Windows, with Eclipse and ImageMagick 6.8.8.-Q16.

I tried with JMagick, but i only got it working with a previous ImageMagick-Version and this had problems converting tifs (every time i got a black image, also in the command line). The newer ImageMagick-Version was not found by the newest JMagick-Version for Windows.

So i tried to use Java Process Builder or the Runtime exec command, for example:

```
 Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"convert","my_image.TIF","dest.TIF"});
```

and

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("convert", "0011D7FE.TIF", "dest.tif");   
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true);   
 try {   
   Process p = pb.start();   
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));   
   String line = null;   
   while((line=br.readLine())!=null){   
       System.out.println(line);   
   }   
   System.out.println(p.waitFor());   
  } catch(Exception e) { }
```

No matter, what command i exactly insert, i always get the error message "Invalid Param - dest.tif" for the second param.

I found this article http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=19679 where the problem is similar and the program tries to use some windows convert function.
So I added the ImageMagick-folder to my system variables and also added a new variable which contains this folder to my project build path in eclipse. But I get still the same error. 
Is there some other place where I have to set up the path? Or any other explanation for the error I get?

Comment: You can either rename Windows' built-in `convert` program as `convertntfs` or rename ImageMagick's `convert` as `IMconvert`. That is probably better than hoping you always remember to set the PATH correctly on all machines.

Comment: Thank you. I renamed ImageMagick's convert into IMconvert and this works fine.

Comment: Excellent! I'll make it as answer, that you can hopefully accept with a lovely big green tick :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer 28-MAR-2017**

Since v7 of **ImageMagick**, the `convert` command has been replaced by `magick` to avoid this very problem. So...

- `convert input.tif output.tif` becomes `magick input.tif output.tif`
- `identify image.jpg` becomes `magick identify image.jpg`
- `compare image.jpg ...` becomes `magick compare image.jpg ...`
- `compose image.jpg ...` becomes `magick compose image.jpg ...`
- `mogrify image.jpg ...` becomes `magick mogrify image.jpg ...`

---

**Original Answer**

You can either rename Windows' built-in `convert` program as `convertntfs` or rename ImageMagick's `convert` as `IMconvert`. That is probably better than hoping you always remember to set the PATH correctly on all machines.